# Default class on element using show/hide multiple divs with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Borrowed my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4vaxE/ from another user and I changed the "click" trigger to "hover". I also created a custom css style for default, but I'd like it to revert to the other link classes when another div is showing.

> HTML code

```
<div class="buttons">
<a class="buttondefault" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a></div>
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
```

> javascript

```
$('#showdiv1').hover(function () {
$('div[id^=div]').hide();
$('#div1').show();
});
$('#showdiv2').hover(function () {
$('div[id^=div]').hide();
$('#div2').show();
});

$('#showdiv3').hover(function () {
$('div[id^=div]').hide();
$('#div3').show();
});

$('#showdiv4').hover(function () {
$('div[id^=div]').hide();
$('#div4').show();
});
```

> CSS

```
.button {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;}
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
    display:none;}
#div1 {
    background:red;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;}
#div2 {
    background:blue;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;}
#div3 {
    background:orange;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;}
#div4 {
    background:green;
    padding:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;}
a {
    color:aqua;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1.0);}
a:hover {
    color:red;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.0);}
a.buttondefault {
    display:cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.0);}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Give your ids a shared class, and call your hide() on the class whenever an item is hovered. This will force all of your divs with that class into the default hidden state on hover, followed immediately by the call to display only the one you are currently hovering. You can do it with an array as well, but it will require considerably more code.

```
<div class="buttons">
<a class="buttondefault" id="showdiv1">Div 1</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a></div>
<div id="div1" class="item">1</div>
<div id="div2" class="item">2</div>
<div id="div3" class="item">3</div>
<div id="div4" class="item">4</div>

$('#div1').hover(function () {
    $('.item').hide();
    $('#div1').show();
});
```